# Apache NiFi: Adding flow file attribute to ExecuteStreamCommand processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to add a property on the ExecuteStreamComamnd processor that should become available as a flowfile attribute to the downstream processor.
Name of the attribute is "dc" with a value of "abc". When I evalute the value of this attibute in the next downstream processor using ${dc} I get an empty value.

[image]

[image: ExecuteStreamComamnd properties]

Whats the correct way to add a new flowfile attribute in this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: You could just add UpdateAttribute Processor right after ExecuteStreamCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic property in ExecuteStreamCommand processor allows you to define environment variable that are passed to the process spawned by this Processor.

This value will not be available in downstream processors.

However you could use UpdateAttribute processor to set attribute of the flow file.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/

Comment: So I should wire a UpdateAttribute processor, with the new attribute, right after the ExecuteStreamCommand processor and then connect that UpdateAttribute processor to any downstream processors. Is that correct?

Comment: That's right. Or place it before ExecuteStreamCommand processor.

Comment: BTW, why you are starting java from nifi? Think about using executegroovyscript processor.

Comment: Thank you daggett, the code was already written in Scala so I am using it.